# RecyclerView Endless scroll is not working in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to implement the Endless scroll with a RecyclerView in a fragment and using addOnScrollListener and onScrolled function is not being called and getChildCount() and findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() is also not returning the correct values

Here is fragment.java code

```
 rcv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
                {
                    isScroll = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems =manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                //Log.d("check", "currentItems "+ currentItems+" totalItem " +totalItems+" scrollOutItems "+scrollOutItems );
                if(isScroll && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems))
                {
                    volley_call();
                    isScroll =false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Here no NestedScrollView is being used in XML file of this fragment. The values that are stored in currentItems and scrollOutItem  are also incorrect

Here is the XML file for this fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        style="@style/fav_top_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/orange_purple"
        android:clickable="true"
        >
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
               android:id="@+id/shapeableImageView"
               style="@style/fav_top_card_img"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:src="@drawable/solo_leveling"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/_27sdp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/sourcesans_semibold"
               android:paddingLeft="15dp"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:text="Continue Reading"
               android:textColor="@color/white"
               android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shapeableImageView" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/_23sdp"
               android:paddingLeft="15dp"
               android:paddingTop="2dp"
               android:text="Solo Levelling chapter 02"
               android:textColor="@color/white"
               android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/imageView5"
               android:layout_width="@dimen/_31sdp"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/_31sdp"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shapeableImageView"
               app:tint="@color/white" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sourcesans_bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Subscribed"
        android:textColor="?attr/inverse_card_text"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:scaleX="-1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_sort_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        tools:context=".Browse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fav_count"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

implement this type of code if you are using pagination

```
recyclerLearnMcqs.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            scroll = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dx > 0) {
                if (scroll) {
                    if (linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() >= mcqsModalList.size() - 1) {
                        scroll = false;
                        last_id = mcqsModalList.size();
                        if (last_id % 10 == 0) {
                            if (mcqsModalList.size() != totalMcq) {
                                hitapi(last_id);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

make sure that the recycler view and layout manager are initialized first...

Comment: How am I supposed to run this when my onScrolled is not being called in first place. And i have tried this also but it didn't work.

Comment: OnScrolled called when you scroll the recycler view otherwise this cannot be called.

Comment: In above the whole layout is scrolling not the  recycler view and the getChildCount() is also not giving correct values

Comment: first, you should track the recycler view position through the layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
rcv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
         isScroll = true;
        
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
           
            if(linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() >= mcqsModalList.size() - 2)
            {
isScroll =false;
                volley_call();
                
            }
        }
    });
```